# Randomely creating a boolean function of N boolean variables

Tags: function, random, boolean-logic, discrete-mathematics

I want to write a program for randomely creating a function that receives as an input N binary values, and maps them into one binary value. The naïve approach would be to create all 2^(2^N) such functions, represented as truth tables, and choose one at random - but this is impractical for large N. In addition, as representing the chosen function in truth table is memory inefficient, it would be desirable to represent it as a formula y = f(x1,x2,...,xN).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assume we have an array `x[1..n]` of Boolean values. The idea is to create an auxiliary Bernoulli Distribution `b` and apply `and` or `or` in sequence with a probability of 50%.

```
1.  result:= true.
    b := Bernoulli(0.5).
2.  For i = 1 To n Do:
3.    If next(b)
        Then result := and(result, x[i])
        Else result := or(result, x[i])
4.  Return result
```

Comment: Thanks! but if I understood your solution correctly, you create a random ad hoc mapping of the input to a boolean result. I want to choose the function in random out of all possble functions (for example, if N=3, a possible chosen function can be f(x1,x2,x3) = x1 and (x2 or x3), another one can be f(x,1,x2,x3) = (x1 or x2) and x3), but once it was chosen, I want to be able to use the same function on different inputs.

Comment: @user1767774 OK. One idea could be to first generate the sequence of `or` and `and` operations at random and then apply it on any different inputs.